# Is there a way in TypeScript to create a new type directly from the keys of an object?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in TypeScript to create a new type directly from the keys of an object?
In the following example TypeScript correctly complains (`'msg' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.`) about msg referring to a value but I was wondering if there is a way to get this working without having to create a separate type definition?

```js
const msg = {okay: 'Okay', cancel: 'Cancel'};

function getMsg(id: keyof msg): string {
   return msg[id];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeof` gets a type from a value. Then you put `keyof` in front of that to get this slightly odd looking type:

```
const msg = {okay: 'Okay', cancel: 'Cancel'};

function getMsg(id: keyof typeof msg): string {
   return msg[id];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAthA5jAvDA3iA1gQwJ4BcMA5APK57EA0MwOYwApgDZHEDC9TzxAvgNwAoQQDMArgygBLcDESMoAWSQAKKQBMiWRnhAiYUPAAdGe+EgCURaACcpYZOkEwXNhWJthziANoaAukK8QA)